# I get a page fault OR a general protection fault when enabling timer interrupts

Tags: c, timer, kernel, x86-64, interrupt

Here is my code: (details at the end)

```
extern timerh
isr_timer:
    push rax
    push rdi
    push rdx
    push rcx
    push rsi
    push rbx
    push rsp
    push rbp
    push r8
    push r9
    push r10
    push r11
    push r12
    push r13
    push r14
    push r15
    call timerh
    pop r15
    pop r14
    pop r13
    pop r12
    pop r11
    pop r10
    pop r9 
    pop r8
    pop rbp
    pop rsp
    pop rbx
    pop rsi
    pop rcx
    pop rdx
    pop rdi 
    pop rax
    iretq
```

```
void timerh(uint64_t t) {
    print("timer\n");
    *EOI = 0;
    return;
}
```

the acpi() functions starts the timer

```
    acpi();
    
    print("testing\n");
```

So if I delete the print("testing"), everything works and the timerh prints consistently, however when the print("testing") is there, it doesnt work, it either gives a GPF or a page fault. The timer might run a couple times but then it errors

Comment: `pop rsp` is the same as `mov rsp, [rsp]`.  `push rsp` / `pop rsp` can't usefully save/restore the stack pointer on the stack.  Either RSP is already pointing at the right place when you restore, in which case it's useless.  Or RSP is pointing somewhere else, so you can't find your saved stuff and reload some other garbage instead.  That's probably unrelated to your problem, just a wasted instruction since `call timerh` will return with RSP unmodified.  (And R12..R15 and RBP and RBX unmodified as well.)

Comment: Where do these GPFs or page faults happen?  What's the  fault-address on them?  Somewhere in code you're not showing?  This doesn't look like a [mcve], and seems missing debugging details.